# Confusion about passing arrays

Tags: c++

Can someone help me with my program? I need to  pass the three arrays into the function called calc_volts and then calculated the volts and then display the values. I keep getting errors that say "unreferenced local variable" or "undeclared idebtufier" for the variables; i, j, k, and volts.

```
    #include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
double calc_volts(double, double, double, int);

int main()
{


    const int max = 10;
    int i; double current[max] = {10.62,14.89,13.21,16.55,19.62,9.47,6.58,18.32,12.15,3.98};

    int j; double volts[max];

    int k; double resistance[max] = {4,8.5,6,7.35,9,15.3,3,5.4,2.9,4.8};



}

double calc_volts(double current[],double volts[], double resistance[], int max)
{
    for (j = 0, j<max, j++)
    volts[j] = current[i]*resistance[k];

    return volts[j];

}
```

Comment: Your function signatures don't match.

Comment: your prototype takes double values as parameters, while your actual implementation takes double-arrays.

Comment: Also: `i`, `j`and `k` are undeclared inside the calc_volts function.

Comment: At a technical level, you can return the last value from calc_volts, but I don't think it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Your confusion seems to be more fundamental than just passing arrays - you aren't even calling the calc_volts function.

Comment: Ok, here is what i have now. It is saying that volts differs in level of indirection. Should i rename something? or what does that mean?

Comment: #include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
double calc_volts(double[], double[], double[], int);


int main()
 
{
 double volts;

 const int max = 10;
 int i; double current[max] = {10.62,14.89,13.21,16.55,19.62,9.47,6.58,18.32,12.15,3.98};
 
 int j; double volts[max];

 int k; double resistance[max] = {4,8.5,6,7.35,9,15.3,3,5.4,2.9,4.8};

 volts = calc_volts(current, resistance, resistance, max);


}

double calc_volts(double current[],double volts[], double resistance[], int max)
{int i, j,k;

 for (j = 0; j<max; j++)
 volts[j] = current[i]*resistance[k];
}

Comment: How do i format my code on herE?

Answer (score 2):

You have many problems:

Your function declaration is wrong:

```
double calc_volts(double, double, double, int);
```

It should be:

```
double calc_volts(double[], double[], double[], int);
```

You must invoke the function in order to use it:

```
int main()
{
    const int max = 10;

    double current[max] = {10.62,14.89,13.21,16.55,19.62,9.47,6.58,18.32,12.15,3.98};

    double volts[max];

    double resistance[max] = {4,8.5,6,7.35,9,15.3,3,5.4,2.9,4.8};

    calc_volts(current, volts, resistance, max); // call the function to execute it    
}
```

The variables `i`, `j` and `k` do not exist inside `calc_volts` because they were declared inside `main`. Variables declared inside a function can only be used inside that function.

To fix the problem just put the declarations inside `calc_volts`.

Comment: in the volts array, that is supposed to be calculated by the calc_volts function. what do you mean i must put values there? how can i get the calc_volts function to pass the values to the volts array, and then display that from the main?

Comment: Once you modify the values of the array, the changes were already made, so you can show the values of the array with a `for` in `main()`.